# How to get the path of the last uploaded image in firebase storage with Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I've learned how to select an image from the gallery, how to upload it into a firebase storage and also display it in `onActivityResult` and everything works fine. My problem is, when i restart the activity the image is gone. This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        StorageReference photoStorageReference = storageReference.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        String path = storageReference.getPath(); //get the path of the last uploaded image
        photoStorageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Picasso.with(StorageActivity.this).load(downloadUri).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have created a method named `displayLastImage()`. When i call this method from `onCreate` like this:

```
private void displayLastImage() {
    StorageReference newStorageReference = storageReference.child("Photos/car.jpg");
    Glide.with(this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(newStorageReference).into(imageView);
}
```

works perfect but when i'm calling the method from `onCreate` using the `path` instead of `"Photos/46"` like this:

```
private void displayLastImage() {
    StorageReference newStorageReference = storageReference.child(path);
    Glide.with(this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(newStorageReference).into(imageView);
}
```

i get this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: childName cannot be null or empty`. How do i get the `path` of the last uploaded image so i can display it correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload an image, you store it at a path that is based on the image the user selected from the gallery.

```
String path = storageReference.getPath();
```

When you restart the activity, the path will not have been initialized, so you're trying to look up an image at an unknown path.

This means that you'll need to "remember" the path between the calls to the activity. You could store it in the Shared Preferences of your app. These are persisted between activities.

More common is to store the image path (or its download URL) in cloud storage, such as the Firebase Database. You can see an example of that in the [Firebase Codelab for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#codelabs).

Comment: I have stored the image path in a Firebase Database and now i can retrieve it correctly. Works perfect! Thank you so much Frank!